# How to filter specific apps for ACTION_PICK intent and add cancel option

Tags: android, android-intent, android-sharing

I want to filter specific app for ACTION_PICK and add remove photo option.

I can do filter specific app but i can not add remove photo option .

i want to  default choose app dialog like whatsapp choose profile photo.

Whatsapp did it.

You can find screenshot below.

Thank you.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must create Activity and register this activity in AndroidManifest.xml

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<activity android:name=".GiveUpActivity"
        android:label="@string/give_up"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_cancel">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:mimeType="image/*"/>
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

And you create intent with your mimeType and startActivityForResult.

After if user select Remove in choose dialog. You handle in onCreate method your GiveUpActivity.

Thanks,